# Camera view shows mirrored scene in BGE

Tags: camera

I suppose something wrong with camera settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Weird - I tried to reproduce this behavior by playing around with available camera parameters without success. Would you mind posting your camera parameters!?

Comment: Is the camera object negatively scaled?

Comment: Uploaded camera parameters, i dont think the object is negatively scaled

Comment: This effect can be produced by scaling your camera negatively along the X axis only, but from your screenshot this isn't the case. However, are there any constraints on the camera that could affect the eventual camera scale? For example, I can attain this effect by adding a Limit Scale constraint with a negative X Maximum set.